# How to improve resolution of Plot?

Tags: plotting

When I plot this expression, the line is a little jagged.

```
V = 10^(-44)*(-21.12213280669467 - 832454.5122565613*Exp[-71.6 r]);
Plot[V, {r, 0, 0.7}]
```

[[image: plot example]

How can I improve the resolution?

Comment: `V = 10^(-44)*(-21.12213280669467 - 832454.5122565613*Exp[-71.6 r]);
Plot[V, {r, 0, 0.7}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4]`

Comment: The result seems great, thanks!